# Adding Space to String at certain places in C++

Tags: c++, string, substring

I am having trouble figuring out the process to add a space in a string at capital letters in C++. If I have a string "HelloWorld", how do I convert that to "Hello World"?

I've tried using substrings and the isupper function but I can't get anything to work.

Edit: this is the code I have. I don't understand why in = newname is not valid code.

```
string breakStringAtCaps(string in) {
string newname[10];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); i++) {
        if (isupper(in[i]) && i != 0) {
            newname[j] = " ";
            j++;
        }
        newname[j] = in[i];
        j++;

    }
    in = newname;
    return in;
}
```

Comment: Please show your code. It is for example a difference if you are talking about `const char*` string literals like "HelloWorld" or about `std::string`.

Comment: @WernerHenze (you are a mind reader sir!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
string breakStringAtCaps(const string& in)
{
    string newname;
    for(int i = 0; i < in.size(); i++)
    {
        if(isupper(in[i]) && i != 0)
            newname += " ";
        newname += in[i];
    }
    return newname;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is the approach I was looking for. Just was assigning the string as an array when I didn't need to

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking right in thinking `substr`, but you implementation is a bit off. If creating an new string containing the contents of the original and inserting a `' '` (space) before each upper-case letter (not including the first), you can seed the new string with the first character of the original using `substr(0,1)` and then use an *auto ranged* `for` loop and `substr(1)` to evaluate each character after the first.

The loop along with a check of `isupper()` is basically all you need, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    std::string s = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "HelloWorld",
                snew = s.substr (0,1);

    if (s.size() > 0)
        for (auto& c : s.substr(1)) {
            if (std::isupper (c))
                snew += " ";
            snew += c;
        }

    std::cout << snew << '\n';
}
```

(the program will use `"HelloWorld"` by default if no string is given as an argument on the command line, otherwise the string given on the command line is used)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/spacebeforeupper
Hello World
```

Or with a string given as an argument:

```
$ ./bin/spacebeforeupper MyDogHasFleas
My Dog Has Fleas
```

Comment: Nice and compact. Is the check `if (s.size() > 0)` required?

Comment: Theoretically you could pass an empty-string, and the first copy of the *nul-terminator* would be handled correctly, but after that when you call `s.substr(1)` to access a value that would be beyond the end of the string, so when thinking about the empty-string case it made sense to add the check.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the strin characters, check if it is a cap and insert a `' '` before if it is one:

It should look like:

```
for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) 
{
    if (str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z') 
    {
        if (i != 0) 
            cout << " "; 
        cout << str[i]; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << str[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just give a implementation, maybe not the best solution:

```
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
void breakStringAtCaps(std::string& in) {
    std::string::const_iterator it = in.begin();
    while(it != in.end()) {
      if(it != in.begin() && isupper(*it)) {
        in.insert(it, ' ');
        it += 2;
    }
    else
        ++it;
    }
}

//
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string str("HelloWorld;");
    breakStringAtCaps(str);
    std::cout << str.c_str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and in your code,

string newname[10];

here 'newname' is a string array's name. you should not assign the name of array to a string instance.
and newname[i] means the i-th string of the array, not the i-th char of a string named 'newname' as you desired.